# How to bypass S-type connector for connecting a servo to an MCU/SoC

Tags: connector, wiring, servo

I have a [TowerPro SG920](http://torqpro.com/?product=sg92r-7) servo that I'd like to connect to an MCU/SoC (Pi or Arduino).

[image]

However, the servo has an "*S-type*" connector (see pic above) and its 3 wires (red, black and orange) are bound/glued/stuck together. In reality I need the three wires to go to 3 different locations, so **can I just cut off the connector and pull the wires apart?** Or does some kind of special care need to be taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In reality I need the three wires to go to 3 different locations, so can I just cut off the connector and pull the wires apart?

Yes. If you don't want to cut the connector off, you can lift the locking tabs and pull the wires out. The connector is a standard 0.1" header.

Alternatively you can use a standard 0.1" header to make an adaptor or extension cord without cutting the original.

[image]

Comment: Or solder three wires to a mating connector (can be simple pin-header, as the pitch, I guess the same).

Comment: @EugeneSh. has a good one, an extension connector can be added which is just a standard pitch pin row header going out to 3 individual wires! I have used this technique to bypass/use different connections on various things recently

Comment: @KyranF It's called "adapter" :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. If it was just a small block which changed connection types yes, but this has wires too, which is why I would call it an extension thingy ;)